# balancing binary tree by rotation ANSI C

Tags: c, binary-tree

I have a binary tree with data from a simple list and now i need to balance it but it keeps giving me the error "segmentation fault (core dumped)"

my balance code is:

```
NodoAB * balance(NodoAB *A){
  int D=0,E=0;
  if(A==NULL)
    return(NULL);

  if(fabs(countNodesAB(A->fe)-countNodesAB(A->fd))<=1)
    return (A);

  if(countNodesAB(A->fe)-countNodesAB(A->fd)<=-2){
    D=countNodesAB(A->fd->fd);
    printf("D:%d\n",D);
    E=countNodesAB(A->fd->fe);
    printf("E:%d\n",E);
    if(E-D==1)
      return(rotationLeft(A));
    else{
      A=rotationRight(A);
      A->fd=rotationLeft(A->fd);
      return(A);
    }
  }
}
```

and one of the rotation code is:

```
 NodoAB * rotationLeft(NodoAB *A){
    NodoAB *aux,*aux2;
    if(A==NULL)
      return(NULL);

    if(A->fd==NULL)
      return(A);

    aux=A;
    A=A->fd;
    aux2=A->fe;
    A->fe=aux;
    aux->fd=aux2;
    return(A);
  }
```

count nodes:

```
int countNodesAB(NodoAB *A){
  if(A==NULL)
    return 0;

  return(1+countNodesAB(A->fe)+countNodesAB(A->fd));
}
```

Comment: Please don't `return (A);`! `return` is not a function.

Comment: @H2CO3 Pity. If it were, it were the function to end all functions.

Comment: @DanielFischer If I sense correctly, we're getting into lambda calculus here... :P

Comment: @H2CO3 That would also be nice, but it was a pun on "the war to end all wars".

Comment: @H2CO3, I fully agree that values used in `return` statements should not be enclosed in parenthesis, however I'd use a different rationale than "it is not a function". Neither `sizeof` nor `typeof` are functions but they are still frequently used with parenthesis. I'd rather say that it's a matter of style and in case of `return` style guides tend to say "don't use parens".

Comment: yeah i learn to use return like this in my first year of programming at university

Comment: @NunoBarros, can `rotationRight` return `NULL`? If it can then the line `A->fd=rotationLeft(A->fd);` can cause a segfault because `A == NULL`.

Comment: sure, just added the function

Comment: @Jan yes it does return NULL if tree is empty the rotationRight is just like rotationLeft but the inverse

Answer (score 0):

The following seems suspicious:

```
if(countNodesAB(A->fe)-countNodesAB(A->fd)<=2){
    D=countNodes(A->fd->fd);
```

If `A->fe` has 2 nodes and `A->fd` has 0 nodes, then it would (I think) imply that `A->fd` is NULL and then result in an access violation on the showns countNodes call (`A->fd->fd` would not be valid).

Comment: then i must be sure that countNodesAB(A->fd)!=0 ?

Comment: Well ... You need to make sure that A->fd is not NULL before you dereference the pointer.

Comment: i got one doubt, i must call the balance function while inserting nodes in the tree right?

Comment: From a technical standpoint, it is possible to balance a binary tree at any time (paying attention to concurrency issues of course).  It would depend on the application requirements.